# Copying indeterminate pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, undefined, undefined-behavior

C11 standard says the following (6.2.4p2):

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during
>   which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists,
>   has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value
>   throughout its lifetime. If an object is referred to outside of its
>   lifetime, the behavior is undefined. **The value of a pointer becomes
>   indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the
>   end of its lifetime.**

The definition of an indeterminate value is (3.19.2):

> either an unspecified value **or a trap representation**

I'm having a bit of a problem with this restriction. I find that if copying intedeterminate pointers was acceptable, a small optimization of the doubly-linked list would be possible. The optimization relies on the following invariants:

- The `prev` pointer of the head element in the list is indeterminate.
- For double-ended lists, the `tail` pointer of an empty list is indeterminate.

Everything else is the same as for normal doubly linked lists. With these invariants, the operations of inserting to the front and removing from the front can be sligthly optimized. In particular (code is for single-ended list only):

```
insertToFront(e)
{
    e->next = head;
    e->prev = NULL;
    if (head) {
        head->prev = e;
    }
    head = e;
}

insertToFrontOptimized(e)
{
    e->next = head;
    if (head) {
        head->prev = e;
    }
    head = e;
}

removeFront()
{
    head = head->next;
    if (head) {
        head->prev = NULL;
    }
}

removeFrontOptimized()
{
    head = head->next;
}
```

Other operations can still work. For example:

```
remove(e)
{
    if (e != head) {
        e->prev->next = e->next;
    } else {
        head = e->next;
    }

    if (e->next) {
        e->next->prev = e->prev; // problem here
    }
}
```

The line above is problematic because when removing the head element, it will set the `prev` pointer of the new head to an indeterminate value. For example, the new `prev` pointer could be a copy of an uninitialized pointer after an `insertToFrontOptimized()`, or it could point to a freed element after a `removeFrontOptimized()`.

But this is only problematic in terms of the C language; the list invariants are not broken because the `prev` pointer of the new head element is allowed to have an indeterminate value.

Does the restriction on the use of indeterminate pointers prevent this optimization? Is there a way around?

Comment: But what's the problem with `head->prev` pointing to garbage? You will never read `head->prev`, you would only ever write to it.

Comment: The problem is that remove() of a first element would read head->prev and set the ->prev of the new head to that value. Adding a check to only do that when it's not removing the first element will reduce performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to touch undefined pointer? Consider this variant:

```
remove(e)
{
    if (e != head) {
        e->prev->next = e->next;
        if (e->next) {
            e->next->prev = e->prev; // NO problem here
        }
    } else {
        head = e->next;
        // OK, new head->prev is undefined now. Who cares?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did for my code, and the other operations could be fixed like that too without extra branches. How obvious :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are worried about the line

```
e->next->prev = e->prev; // problem here
```

invoking undefined behavior because `e->prev` can be indeterminate at a time when it is executed.

It is probably good to worry about this, [even if your architecture does not have trap representations. C compilers have a tendency to treat access to indeterminate objects as undefined behavior, even if the recent standards seem more nuanced than that](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/03/13/indeterminate-undefined).

If I were you I would reassure myself by using this line in substitution:

```
memcpy(&e->next->prev, &e->prev, sizeof(e->prev);
```

It will probably be compiled to the same instruction(s) you would have expected for the original assignment. The only drawback is that according to `memcpy()`'s specification, `&e->next->prev` and `&e->prev` must be distinct when the call is made, whereas the assignment `e->next->prev = e->prev;` allows them to overlap exactly.

This said, this is one question that it would really help to have a formal semantic of C to answer, and the formal semantics I know of (KCC, CompCert, …) would all allow you to copy an indeterminate variable over another of the exact same type.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Anyway I think wrapping the pointers in structures will work too (and maybe a bit more elegant and without relying on memcpy optimization), because structures are guaranteed to not have trap representations. Sorry, I was forced to accept Roman's answer since that is how I fixed my problem ;)